# SASS - Generating Variables with Loop

Tags: list, loops, variables, sass

## TL;DR

Can SASS functions be used to generate SASS variables? My intention is to take a small set of colors and process them into many shades and tints of those colors.

## The Problem:

**N.B.** I'm using https://github.com/at-import/color-schemer for the color functions.

I have the following variables:

```
$root-color:    hsl(10, 85%, 45%);

$red:        $root-color;
$vermilion:  ryb-adjust-hue($red, 30);
$orange:     ryb-adjust-hue($red, 60);
$amber:      ryb-adjust-hue($red, 90);
$yellow:     ryb-adjust-hue($red, 120);
$chartreuse: ryb-adjust-hue($red, 150);
$green:      ryb-adjust-hue($red, 180);
$teal:       ryb-adjust-hue($red, 210);
$blue:       ryb-adjust-hue($red, 240);
$violet:     ryb-adjust-hue($red, 270);
$purple:     ryb-adjust-hue($red, 300);
$magenta:    ryb-adjust-hue($red, 330);
```

For each color, I'm trying to produce the following output (`$red` shown below):

```
$red-10: $red;

$red-01: shade($red-10, 90);
$red-02: shade($red-10, 80);
$red-03: shade($red-10, 70);
$red-04: shade($red-10, 60);
$red-05: shade($red-10, 50);
$red-06: shade($red-10, 40);
$red-07: shade($red-10, 30);
$red-08: shade($red-10, 20);
$red-09: shade($red-10, 10);

$red-11: tint($red-10, 10);
$red-12: tint($red-10, 20);
$red-13: tint($red-10, 30);
$red-14: tint($red-10, 40);
$red-15: tint($red-10, 50);
$red-16: tint($red-10, 60);
$red-17: tint($red-10, 70);
$red-18: tint($red-10, 80);
$red-19: tint($red-10, 90);
```

I can boil this down to the following:

For each `$color`:

- `$red-10: $red;`
- For 1 - 9 `($1)`: Generate variable `$#{$color}-0$1: shade($red-10, (100 - ($1 * 10)))`
- For 1 - 9 `($1)`: Generate variable `$#{$color}-($1 * 10): tint($red-10, ($1 * 10))`

Obviously I get an error:

`Error: Invalid CSS after "...m 1 through 9 {": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "#{$color}-$1: shade"`

I've looked into using lists and `@append` but as I have x colors I'm thinking I'd have to create dynamic lists? Is that even possible?

I'm aware that I'm both using a variable to create a variable (`$#{$color}`)and trying to output a function within the loops, and am not sure if this is even possible with SASS.

If not, is there a better workflow for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currentry Sass does not allow to access or create variables dynamically. The only way to achieve so, is to use maps. And, if you have a variable number of colors, then you could use a map where each key (the color name) contains a list of all the generated colors, so you could keep track of them.

**Note** i changed the color functions and values for testing purposes only (changed `shade` to `lighten` and `tint` to `darken`; also in the the `tint` loop, i added a `- 100` to the value, to keep the darken value between 1 and 100). You should replace those functions with yours.

```
// Colors to use
$colors:(
    red:  red,
    blue: blue
);

// Generated color lists
$generated: ();

// For each defined color
@each $name, $color in $colors {

    // Current color map
    $current : ();

    // Generates the colors transformations (shades)
    @for $i from 1 through 9 {
        $current: append($current, lighten($color, (100 - ($i * 10))));
    }

    // Adds the current color
    $current: append($current, $color);

    // Generates the colors transformations (tints)
    @for $i from 11 through 19 {
        $current: append($current, darken($color, ($i * 10) - 100));
    }

    // If the map has not been created
    @if map-has-key($generated, $name) == false {
        $generated: map-merge($generated, ($color : $current));
    }

}

// Create a function to get the desired color
@function get-color($color, $index: 10) { // Default to base color

    // Get the desired color map
    $list: map-get($generated, $color);

    // Return the color index
    @return nth($list, $index);

}
```

Then you could use the created function to get the color idex of your choice:

```
.foo {
    color: get-color(blue, 5);
}
```

You can check the working example [here](https://gist.github.com/ae9b45394e1425cc22c0cea4be8dcbbc).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation, example, and code comments... Works a treat! :)